# Multiple image preview using V-for when uploading (Vue JS)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Image not showing on loop using :ref

I am using FileReader() to read the field.

> Vue Component

```
<div v-for="(image, index) in imgFile" :key="index">
<img :ref="'image'+parseInt( index )">
{{image.name}}
</div>
<input type="file" class="file-upload-default" @change="onFileChange" multiple>
<span style="cursor:pointer" class="file-upload-browse">
<img src="/addmore.png" height="50" width="50">
</span>

export default{
onFileChange(e){
var selectedFiles = e.target.files;
for (var i=0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++){
  this.imgFile.push(selectedFiles[i]);
}

if (selectedFiles) {
  for (var i=0; i < this.imgFile.length; i++){
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('load', function(){          
     this.$ref["image"+parseInt( i )][0].src = reader.result;         
   }.bind(this), false); 
     reader.readAsDataURL(this.imgFile[i]);
   }
     }
   }
 }
```

I want to show the images which is selected from eventListener.

Comment: What is `key` in your template in the `<img>` tag?

Comment: You might also want to use `this.$refs` instead of `this.$ref`

Comment: ...and it is probably better and easier to encapsulate the logic into its own component.

Comment: I could understand. Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Sorry **key**  was  a Typo. I edited my Question

Comment: I've added an example to restructure your question.

Answer (score 0):

Improve your architecture by splitting your logic into two components. You can do this like this:

```html
<template>
  <div class="parent-component">
    <image-component :image="image" v-for="(image, index) in images" :key="index" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ParentComponent',
  data () {
    return {
      images: []
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="image-component">
    <img ref="imgElement">
    {{ image.name }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ChildComponent',
  props: {
    image: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...
  },
  mounted () {
    // you don't have to loop here, because in the scope of the image-component,
    // you only have one `<img>`-tag. the loop is in the parent component
    console.log(this.$refs.imgElement);
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Like this, you only have to care about one image and not always loop and have an index. If you want to pass an object to the parent element, you can use `this.$emit('an-event', data);` and catch it within the parent on the `<image-component @an-event="method($event)">`